# Кодировка Wordpress

Tags: кодировка, wordpress

Значит, сижу я верстаю меню, и тут после обновления страницы [image: на]

Это из-за чего такое страшное могло произойти?

**Обновление**

И это происходит именно при активации моего шаблона, может быть, куда задать что надо или, наоброт, убрать? Только где?

Comment: Давай содержимое functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, надо в .php-файлах темы сделать кодировку UTF-8 без BOM.